# Activate Insert(Key) inside a DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I activate the Insert-key inside a `DatePicker` in WPF?

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateTpicker"
              SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
              DisplayDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
              PreviewTextInput="ActivateInsertKey"/>

private void ActivateInsertKey()
{
    // activate Insert-key ?????
}
```

Comment: Are you saying, if you have a date in there already, you want it to be able to start at the first character and just overtype everything?

Comment: I want to overwrite certain numbers. For example if i have 15.04.2013 and I want to change only 1 before 5 than I don't want to delete 1 and write 2, but I place the cursor before 1 and write 2 (25.04.2013). In that case 2 will overwrite 1. This is what the Insert-Key does.

Comment: I fully understand what the Insert does - I just didn't really understand what or even why you wanted that? Let me see if there's a way you can work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a38c6aec-81a2-4b1c-9a77-c0ae890c1363/) (see last posting):

```
PropertyInfo textEditorProperty = typeof (TextBox).GetProperty(
   "TextEditor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
object textEditor = textEditorProperty.GetValue(hexTextBox, null);

// set _OvertypeMode on the TextEditor
PropertyInfo overtypeModeProperty = textEditor.GetType().GetProperty(
   "_OvertypeMode", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
overtypeModeProperty.SetValue(textEditor, true, null);
```

I created a method in the code behind and `Copy/Pasted` the code above.